# Visual Studio 2017: A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

When executing unit tests in debugging mode, I get the following error message:

```
A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. For more 
details please see the Microsoft Help and Support web site. 
HRESULT=0x8000ffff. ErrorCode=0x0.
```

Answer (score 18):

So my steps to fix the issue,

1- [Preventive action] 
   Update the Visual studio 2017 , from the yellow flag notification or from

```
Tools >> Extensions & Updates >> Updates >> visual studio marketplace.
```

2- Search in your test solution for **launchsettings.json** file and remove it.

3- Clean the test solution .

4- Rebuild the project .

5- Make a cup of coffee ;).

Comment: This worked for me until I upgraded to version 15.5.7. Now it doesn't fix it anymore

Comment: Why is this the answer? It helped me, but why?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Visual Studio solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the solution didn't work for me, and I couldn't find a launchsettings.json.

What eliminated the error for me: Changing the Startup project to a *project other than the test project*, as mentioned in [this MSDN forum post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/182983/test-explorer-fatal-error-trying-to-debug-unit-tes.html).

Comment: It was the opposite to me, but your answer really led me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Clean the solution and try again. See [Visual Studio Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74ff4ca5-4df8-48f7-b2c9-2f54b6b59c2c/a-fatal-error-has-occurred-and-debugging-needs-to-be-terminated-for-more-details-please-see-the?forum=visualstudiogeneral) for details. It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your depencency packages and references and try to ensure that all is ok. I fix this problem delete unnecessary and broke dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was because of the .Net Framework Target settings were wrong. It was set to .NET 5.0 which was not supported by VS2017. Opening the project in VS2019 solved the issue.